# Parse.com : installed latest SDK but now App not working

Tags: parse-platform

My IOS App. Twoater has been up and running successfully for a couple of months now.

I downloaded the latest SDK and implemented the parse.framework :
- deleted old framework from within xCode
- dropped new one into xCode
- checked parse.framework in Build Phases tab

All looks OK.

When I try to build the code I fails in 2 classes where I have the following statement relating to PFQueryTableViewController. See code

---

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

### @interface TwoatsTVC : PFQueryTableViewController

### And get Error :

### "Cannot find the interface declaration for 'PFQueryTableViewController' ... did you mean UITableViewController

Any ideas welcome ...

Many thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try importing the ParseUI framework that is included with the SDK.

-Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael, done this but still the same issue.  Do I need to #import a header in addition to <Parse/Parse.h>

Comment: I am not allowed to Post An Answer so I will flag Michael's answer as correct and add the additional text here :

Comment: Solution :
1- import the ParseUI as suggested by Michael (thanks Michael)
2- add a new import into the class :

    #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>

-Guy

Comment: You need to import both ParseUI and Parse.  You can do this like so:  #import <Parse/Parse.h>  #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>